# What is the difference between __assertedDate and assertedDate in hl7 FHIR json schema?

Tags: jsonschema, hl7-fhir

In most of the JSON schemas of hl7 FHIR resources, i found fields prefixed with _. But they are not listed in the examples. So while creating classes for the resources, shall I go only with fields not prefixed with _.

Like _assertedDate and assertedDate. Whether both fields are needed or not?

Because, for same resources in xml schema definition, I dont find _assertedDate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to read the details about the json format at http://build.fhir.org/json.html (particularly http://build.fhir.org/json.html#primitive), and see http://build.fhir.org/observation-example-10minute-apgar-score.json for an example

Comment: Thank you @Grahame Grieve :-), for the detailed information.